# React, Nest - How to set cookie

Tags: reactjs, cookies, nest, setcookie

I'm currently developing a reservation system and the authentication I use is JWT and saving it in my cookie.This is how I send the cookie after the user login.

- React Login

```
  const login = async () => {
    const requestOptions = {
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      withCredentials: true,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      path: '/',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        id: "User ID",
        password: "Password"
      })
    };

    fetch('https://localhost:4000/auth/login', requestOptions)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => {
        console.log('result login', response)
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log('[error] login', e)
      })
    // empty dependency array means this effect will only run once (like componentDidMount in classes)
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    login()
  }, []);
```

- Nest JS

```
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  @UseGuards(LocalGuard)
  @Post('login')
  async login(
    @Body() data: UserLoginDto,
    @Res({ passthrough: true }) res: Response,
  ) {
    console.log('[LOGIN]', data);
    const access_token = this.authService.login(data);

    res.cookie('access_token', access_token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true,
      sameSite: 'none',
      path: '/',
      maxAge: 10000,
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 1000),
    });
    return access_token;
  }
```

then I can see a cookie data like this.

[image: Cookie data]

However, It isn't stored in my browser.
[image]

I'd tried credentials, https, httpOnly, Secure, sameSite, expires options. But these didn't working and still get in.
Is there way to store cookie? Please help me.

## Fix and New Error

I stored my cookie! But I got Cors error. I think access-control-allow-origin: * is problem. Therefore, I fixed my code like this

- Nest Js

```
  app.enableCors({
    origin: [
      'https://127.0.0.1:3000',
      'https://localhost:3000',
    ],
    credentials: true,
    // methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    // allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
    // maxAge: 86400,
  });
```

but 'access-control-allow-origin' isn't changed.
[image: access-control-allow-origin: *]

How can I fix access-control-allow-origin?

Comment: This is almost certainly a browser behavior issue.  Is it actually https in your browser URL?

Comment: Yes, I'm using https with SSL Key

Comment: @possum I stored my cookie!! But I got Cors error. I think access-control-allow-origin: * is problem. I edit my post. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is your testing environment, so the React app is running on a different port than the Nest.js app, right?

Your Nest app needs to allow the React app's origin for CORS. Add this to your main.ts:

```
app.enableCors({
   origin: [
      'http://localhost:3000',
   ],
   credentials: true,
});
```

Replace the port number with the port of your React app.

Further reading on CORS, if you're interested: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Edit: After reading your cookie configuration again, it might also be an issue with those. It seems you're running the app on localhost, but having `secure` set to true, which won't work for a non-HTTPS environment. I'd suggest setting `secure` conditionally, depending on if the app is running locally or in production. Also the `credentials: 'same-origin'` configuration might not work for different ports.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you commenting out the methods allowed? To enable cors, you should specify the origins and the methods allowed. Uncomment the methods option and it should work:

```
app.enableCors({
    origin: [
      'https://localhost:3000',
    ],
    credentials: true,
    // you can list out only the methods you are interested in
    methods: ['GET', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'DELETE'];,
  });
```